# What does $dz^2$ mean?

Tags: notation, complex-geometry

I'm reading a paper ("La Formule de Verlinde" by Christoph Sorger) and at a certain point, the author switches from algebro geometric language to complex geometric language. He uses the symbol $dz^2$, where $z$ is a local complex coordinate on a Riemann surface. Can anyone explain what this means, either in the language of algebraic geometry or of real smooth manifolds? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be the symmetric $(0,2)$-tensor given by
$$dz^2 = dz\otimes dz.$$

Comment: Ah, this seems to be right. Thanks.